# Transparent material is "see through" when rendered in Cycles

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv, node-editor

So I have a model that is separated into a few pieces and each piece has it's own material, the nose piece has a material transparency problem. I have the nodes set up correctly but the material only turns transparent when in Material Preview mode and when I use "Alpha Blend" in the blend mode options, in Cycles Render it makes the material "see through".

[image: donkey]

Now the weird thing is that the material stays black when switching to the other blend modes... but turns transparent when I move the nose piece slightly. I could fix it by moving the nose piece veeery slightly but I would rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why it appeared transparent but I found a workaround, I just used a second UV map. I didn't know you could use multiple UV maps...